# how to click a button with selenium on a javascript page

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

how to make selenium click a button like

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="ajax_more_button">さらに読み込む</a>
```

literally, have no 'button' type to it?

Hello, I'm trying to scrape urls from https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/, a news website.
To have access to more articles, there's a button `さらに読み込む`(read more).

[image]

I tried to click the button with selenium with the following code which returned an error message below.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "さらに読み込む")))
button.click()
```

the whole error message:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (377, 485). Other element would receive the click: 
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.199)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0072A813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x006BC4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x005C5358]
    (No symbol) [0x005F5062]
    (No symbol) [0x005F3B98]
    (No symbol) [0x005F239B]
    (No symbol) [0x005F179E]
    (No symbol) [0x005E9F5C]
    (No symbol) [0x0060A73C]
    (No symbol) [0x005E9A36]
    (No symbol) [0x0060AA94]
    (No symbol) [0x0061C922]
    (No symbol) [0x0060A536]
    (No symbol) [0x005E82DC]
    (No symbol) [0x005E93DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0098AABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x009CA78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x009C456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x007B51E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x006C5F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x006C2328]
    (No symbol) [0x006C240B]
    (No symbol) [0x006B4FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75C87D59+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x771AB74B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x771AB6CF+191]
```

I have no idea how to do that, maybe there's a better library to do that in Python?

Comment: `<a>` is a link element. Get the link element, and then call the `click()` method on it.

Comment: Does the error message continue with "Other element would receive the click"? Please post the full error. It doesn't matter that it's not a button.

Comment: the whole <a> is like 
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="ajax_more_button">さらに読み込む</a>.
don't think theres a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the complete solution:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
import time

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2})

driver = Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/')

element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ajax_more_button")))

count = len(wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul#latest_list>li[class="p-list-item "]'))))
print(f"initial number of articles: {count}")

while True:

    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].click()", element)
    time.sleep(1)
    new_count = len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul#latest_list>li[class="p-list-item "]'))
    print(f"articles after clicking read/load more button: {new_count}")
    if new_count>count:
        count = new_count
    else:
        break

    # remove this "if statement" if you want to continue clicking and loading more articles.
    if count==100:
        break

news_articles = [i.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('href') for i in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul#latest_list>li[class="p-list-item "]')]

print(news_articles)
print(f"Total articles {len(news_articles)}")
```

output:

```
initial number of articles: 20
articles after clicking read/load more button: 30
articles after clicking read/load more button: 40
articles after clicking read/load more button: 50
articles after clicking read/load more button: 60
articles after clicking read/load more button: 70
articles after clicking read/load more button: 80
articles after clicking read/load more button: 90
articles after clicking read/load more button: 100
['https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230707-OYT1T50249/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230707-OYT1T50246/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230706-OYT1T50325/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230706-OYT1T50322/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230705-OYT1T50244/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230705-OYT1T50241/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230704-OYT1T50239/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230704-OYT1T50236/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230703-OYT1T50226/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230703-OYT1T50223/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230702-OYT1T50218/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230702-OYT1T50215/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230701-OYT1T50247/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230701-OYT1T50244/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230630-OYT1T50265/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230630-OYT1T50259/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230629-OYT1T50195/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230629-OYT1T50192/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230628-OYT1T50240/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230628-OYT1T50237/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230627-OYT1T50257/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230627-OYT1T50254/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230626-OYT1T50297/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230626-OYT1T50292/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230625-OYT1T50191/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230625-OYT1T50188/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230624-OYT1T50186/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230624-OYT1T50183/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230623-OYT1T50305/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230623-OYT1T50302/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230623-OYT1T50083/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230623-OYT1T50070/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230621-OYT1T50273/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230621-OYT1T50270/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230620-OYT1T50203/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230620-OYT1T50200/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230619-OYT1T50253/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230619-OYT1T50250/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230618-OYT1T50138/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230618-OYT1T50135/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230617-OYT1T50290/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230617-OYT1T50287/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230616-OYT1T50258/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230616-OYT1T50254/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230616-OYT1T50013/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230616-OYT1T50010/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230614-OYT1T50286/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230614-OYT1T50284/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230613-OYT1T50164/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230613-OYT1T50161/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230612-OYT1T50193/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230612-OYT1T50189/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230610-OYT1T50273/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230610-OYT1T50270/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230609-OYT1T50270/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230609-OYT1T50267/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230608-OYT1T50261/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230608-OYT1T50257/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230607-OYT1T50239/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230607-OYT1T50236/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230606-OYT1T50228/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230606-OYT1T50225/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230605-OYT1T50252/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230605-OYT1T50244/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230604-OYT1T50144/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230604-OYT1T50141/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230603-OYT1T50230/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230603-OYT1T50227/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230602-OYT1T50262/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230602-OYT1T50259/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230601-OYT1T50232/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230601-OYT1T50229/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230531-OYT1T50307/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230531-OYT1T50304/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230530-OYT1T50254/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230530-OYT1T50251/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230529-OYT1T50201/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230529-OYT1T50198/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230528-OYT1T50116/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230528-OYT1T50113/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230527-OYT1T50305/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230527-OYT1T50301/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230526-OYT1T50307/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230526-OYT1T50304/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230525-OYT1T50378/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230525-OYT1T50371/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230524-OYT1T50273/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230524-OYT1T50270/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230523-OYT1T50272/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230523-OYT1T50269/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230522-OYT1T50192/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230522-OYT1T50189/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230521-OYT1T50225/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230520-OYT1T50354/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230520-OYT1T50351/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230519-OYT1T50244/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230518-OYT1T50235/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230518-OYT1T50232/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230517-OYT1T50298/', 'https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/editorial/20230517-OYT1T50295/']
Total articles 100
```

Few things to note:

- as we load the home page, initially it contains `20 articles` under the `最新ニュース` section.
- on every click on the button `さらに読み込む` , it loads 10 more articles and so on.
- as you may notice, to click on the desired button, we used `driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].click()", element)`
- there could be thousands of articles on the page. And if you wish to load more, simply remove the `if count==100:` statement or increase the count number to load a given number of articles. Please notice that as every click loads 10 more articles, the value of the variable `count` will be a multiple of 10 starting from 20. (20, 30, 40, 50,....and so on)

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>さらに読み込む</kbd> element is a dynamic element, so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "さらに読み込む"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#ajax_more_button"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='ajax_more_button' and contains(., 'さらに読み込む')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: yomiuri]

Comment: I don't think your solution is any different than mine other than the waiting time. Strange that it just dosn't work for me.